# The repository directory generated with "Eclipse product export"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When I [export the standalone headless eclipse RCP](http://prosseek.blogspot.com/2012/12/headless-rcp-standalone.html), I have two directories: eclipse and repository. What is the repository directory for? Can I just delete this directory?

I see the plugins directory is in both eclipse and repository.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a p2 repository that is being generated for the plugins/features you are exporting which is used for provisioning if you unfamiliar with that here is a link [Equinox p2](http://eclipse.org/equinox/p2/) Sounds like you don't need if you are not sure what it is. In the product export wizard there is a check box you can uncheck to generate repository metadata which I think its called. And to answer your question, yes you can delete it and it will have no impact on the application.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Duncan's answer, I unchecked the "Generate metadata repository" not to generate the directory.

[image]